# Getting the jar file that defines fileset prior to using the fileset in ant build (+ ivy)

Tags: ant, task, ivy, lifecycle

We have a jar that defines ant tasks and also creates a new fileset to locate some server specific jar files.

If I keep the jar file locally in the build it works fine because ant during the parse time is able to define the fileset.

However, I would like to download the file from a repo first and then sort of load it to define the fileset and the tasks as well. We are using ant + ivy.

But it seems that you cannot run targets to get the jar file before creating the extended fileset that depends on the jar. Having only tasks seems an easier task to get with ivy but not sure how to load jar that define filesets prior to defining them.

So below I have the server-module special fileset that is defined in ant-tasks.jar file. I wish there was a way to execute a get task and then define the path or something like that

```
<path id="ant-task.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="${prj.dir}/ant" includes="ant-tasks.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef resource="antlib.xml"
         classpathref="ant-task.lib.path"/>


<server-module id="javax-servlet-api.jar" module="javax-servlet-api" modulesdir="${server-modules.dir}"/>
```

I am hoping this makes sense and any suggestion is appreciated.

The example here talks about a different scenario and not helping in my case:

[How can I use an Ant taskdef that depends on lib imported by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178395/how-can-i-use-an-ant-taskdef-that-depends-on-lib-imported-by-ivy)

Thank you!

Comment: The ant jar in my case defines more than just the tasks. It defines filesets as well. So it is not the same as the other question. Loading tasks seems ok but loading filesets seems to happen before tasks are even loaded.

Comment: I found the answer: just a simple get task before the taskdef or typedef would get the jar first and then ant compiles filesets. It seems that my scenario was way simple than the other case and so is the understanding of ant unfortunately.